# Interrupting a computationally intensive task

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

Suppose I have a Node program doing a computationally intensive task, say solving a Boolean satisfiability problem using the DPLL algorithm, could take a minute or a million years with no way of knowing which in advance, I want to set a timeout of one hour so if a solution isn't found by then, the task should be abandoned.

One way to do it would be to set a timer that calls process.exit.

Is there a way to interrupt a computationally intensive task but then continue in the same process, without exiting the process?

Comment: are you running an recursive function or loop ? cant  you just stop it ?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix Recursive functions. By 'just stop it' do you mean litter the working code with calls to check for timeout and throw an exception? Sure, but am hoping for a solution that doesn't incur the maintenance and runtime overhead of that.

Comment: assuming the script that you run does only that one task I see no way of it to continue in the same process unless it has additional functionality like http server, nothing can keep it running and it will exit.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix No, the specific functionality I have in mind is, suppose I have a list of Boolean satisfiability problems, I want the program to go through them, solving as many as possible; if it gets stuck on one, it should go onto the next.

Comment: A normal way of handling this would be to use some 'worker pool' module (there is a bunch of them available), which will run you task(s) in a different process and just kill it in case of a timeout. The overhead of killing and then re-instantiating a rogue process, should be absolutely negligible compared to the timeout itself. If you still want to handle the timeout in inside the very same process, your application code should track it explicitly, e.g. by invoking some predefined `timeout.check()` utility method, during an each iteration of your algorithm.